# Grunt livereload doesn't show ssi changes

Tags: gruntjs, ssi, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm using grunt with [connect-include](https://github.com/zeevl/connect-include)

My pages are rendered perfectly, but when I change my templates (for instance /templates/*.html) which are included with ssi, somehow my page doesn't get updated with the new changes to the template file. My page does reload, but with the old html. Probably my watch task is watching the index.html and doesn't see any changes made to the file

This is my **connect** setup:

```
connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        open: true,
        livereload: 35729,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
        hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          middleware: function(connect) {

            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              ssInclude(config.app),
              connect().use('/bower_components', connect.static('./bower_components')),
              connect.static(config.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
```

My **watch** task

```
livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
        ]
      }
```

Here's an index.html example

```
<html>
<body>
<!-- #include file="templates/header.html" -->
</body>
</html>
```

Now, when i change the header.html my page gets reloaded, but I can't see the changes made in header.html

I can't figure out how to solve this problem, besides editting the index.html file each time I change a template

**UPDATE:**
Figured out it probably has someting to to with the status 304 not modified, but how can I force the index.html to be modified with livereload?

**UPDATE 2**
Found myself a workaround, but this is obvisouly not the right way to do it :-)
I've created a copy task for the index.html file every time one of my templates changes

```
copy: {

      index: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
        dest: '<%= config.app %>',
        src: ['*.html'],
        flatten: true
      }
}
```

This will change he modification date of the file. I've also added an extra watch task to make things complete

```
watch: { 

      html: {
        files: ['<%= config.app %>/componenten/*.html', '<%= config.app %>/templates/*.html'],
        tasks: ['copy:index']
      }
}
```

Is there another way to change a files modification time?